# Yii2 File Validation .tar.xz

Tags: file-upload, yii2

How can I limit file upload to .tar.xz extension only ?
Example (not working, only with xz):

```
[['file1'], 'file','extensions' => 'tar.xz']
```

So far I have only obtained success for non-composite extensions (zip, xz, etc)

Comment: Do you mean that `file.foo.xz` could be uploaded? i.e it validates the name after last dot only?

Comment: However, try the following: 1- Add escaping `\` to the dot to be `tar\.xz` 2- Try to use array instead of string i.e `...'extensions' => ['tar.xz']]` and also try to escape the dot in array too. Please, let me to know if it has been succeeded.

Comment: Thanks @SaidbakR,
He validates the name after last dot only. I tried what you suggested but it didn't work. :(

Comment: I have registered an issue ticket for feature request on their repo. [Checkout it](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/18094)

Comment: Currently, in Yii 2.0.36 composite file extension is supported

Answer (score 0):

**As from version 2.0.36** of [yii2](/questions/tagged/yii2), you probably do the following to allow composite extension validation:

```
[['file1'], 'file','extensions' => 'tar.xz', 'checkExtensionByMimeType' => false]
```

The option `checkExtensionByMimeType` is introduced if the mimetype of the extension is not compatible with the extension. for example, if you make a text file with an extension like `ant.fox`